# Posting to Facebook Page using API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to posting a post to a facebook page I created. I have created an app for that. And given the AppID, AppSecret, PageID and User Access Token to my application. But when I tried to publish a post, I get the following error in my application.

> Facebook error: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \ either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \ and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \ requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \ sufficient administrative permission

I have given the pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts when I created the user access token.
I have tried with creating different apps, but still getting the same error message.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: You cant post to a group unless an admin of that group installed your app there

Comment: you need the page access token to post to a page, check /me/accounts with your user access token to find the right one.